# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dto.VerbInfoDTO

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am getting below error while calling the url with API manager.

**Detailed error**

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-06-13 06:26:45,558] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker} - Error processing GET request for : /test/test. java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dto.VerbInfoDTO
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.throttling.APIThrottleHandler.doRoleBasedAccessThrottling_aroundBody14(APIThrottleHandler.java:628)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.throttling.APIThrottleHandler.doRoleBasedAccessThrottling(APIThrottleHandler.java:505)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.throttling.APIThrottleHandler.doThrottle_aroundBody4(APIThrottleHandler.java:238)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.throttling.APIThrottleHandler.doThrottle(APIThrottleHandler.java:195)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.throttling.APIThrottleHandler.handleRequest_aroundBody0(APIThrottleHandler.java:174)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.throttling.APIThrottleHandler.handleRequest(APIThrottleHandler.java:162)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:367)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcessNonDefaultStrategy(RESTRequestHandler.java:149)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:95)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:71)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:327)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:98)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:368)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:189)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
```

Comment: Hi Balananda, Which version of WSO2 API Manager are you using? Will you be able to give the exact steps you tried so that we can see what causes this error?

Comment: I am seeing error after upgrading from 2.6. to 3.1.0.

Comment: Hi Balananda, thank you for the response. This issue was not encountered before when testing. Will you be able to please let us know the sample request format that you used to invoke this API? Hope you followed all the steps provided in https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/upgrading-wso2-api-manager/upgrading-from-260-to-310/ when migrating from 2.6.0 to 3.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to the used throttle handler(in synapse-configs API definition) **APIThrottleHandler** is the old one and it is used as below.

```
<handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.throttling.APIThrottleHandler">
         <property name="policyKey" value="gov:/apimgt/applicationdata/tiers.xml"/>
         <property name="policyKeyApplication"
                   value="gov:/apimgt/applicationdata/app-tiers.xml"/>
         <property name="id" value="A"/>
         <property name="policyKeyResource"
                   value="gov:/apimgt/applicationdata/res-tiers.xml"/>
</handler>
```

And it is not accepting an array as per the [implementation](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/release-6.6.137-c236/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/gateway/handlers/throttling/APIThrottleHandler.java#L628).

This could be overcome by switching to the new throttle handler(**ThrottleHandler**) by modifying synapse configs of each API as below.

```
<handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.throttling.ThrottleHandler">
         <property name="policyKey" value="gov:/apimgt/applicationdata/tiers.xml"/>
         <property name="policyKeyApplication"
                   value="gov:/apimgt/applicationdata/app-tiers.xml"/>
         <property name="id" value="A"/>
         <property name="policyKeyResource"
                   value="gov:/apimgt/applicationdata/res-tiers.xml"/>
</handler>
```

Hope this will help.